# Phone reboots randomly

Tags: reboot, system-error, logging, system-freeze, redmi-note-4

Bought 'Redmi Note 4' phone a year ago. Random reboot issue started happening after 6 months. Did root & had flashed old/new/unofficial ROMS on my phone afterwards, uninstalled CPU hogging apps still it didn’t fix. Tried every single post from MIUI forum but no luck. Recorded ADB logcat to trace system logs on my PC.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

*Current phone details Screenshot =>*

[image]

*Here, 26 seconds log filtered with only ‘Error’ tag just before it hanged & rebooted itself on its own =>*
https://justpaste.it/3m8rd

Comment: You rooted after the issues presented or before?

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths Ofc afterwards to verify whether this issue also persist in older/custom firmware.

Comment: Have flashed new persist.img from a proper official ROM. Has been 3 days & it still boots randomly :(